# What do game designers do for the game?

Tags: game-design, level-design

One day I asked me: "How do game designers work?". I knew what the "main mission" of their work, but I didn't know: "How to do it?" and "What do they need to write?"

I want to know full "list" of terms with examples that they need to write.

For example:

Genre - Action

Setting - Retrofuturism etc...

Please answer me :)

Comment: In the words of my colleague Liz England, one of my personal game design heroes, [the game designer solves The Door Problem](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/LizEngland/20140423/216092/quotThe_Door_Problemquot_of_Game_Design.php). Read through that list, then multiply it by every object, character, and mechanic in your game. [Extra Credits also has an accessible overview of the role](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQvWMdWhFCc). See also, [What does a game designer do?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5368/39518)

Comment: As you can see from those examples, a complete accounting of *everything* a game designer does is too broad for us to reasonably capture in a concise answer here. Can you try to narrow down the problem? Is there a specific part of your current game's design that you're unsure how to approach or break down into design tasks? If so, try editing your question to give us more details about the game you're working on, and the aspect of it that you're stuck on atm, and we can re-open this question to try to give you more focused guidance for your specific case.